# cant make multiple routes dynamically in Android Maps api v2

Tags: java, android, api, maps

i am familiar about polyline api in android. Its easy to get route between two static points.

But i want to trace route dynamically for multiple users.

Here is my basic logic:

```js
//Insert function is called every 10 secs

insert(){
  
   for(int i=0;i<nameid.size();i++) {

 LatLng a = new LatLng(latid.get(i), longid.get(i)); 
  map.addmarker(new MarkerOptions().position(a));
}
  
}
```

Lets consider i have 2 users A and B. I want 1 route between old and new position of user A  and other route between old and new position of user B.

But by my logic i am able to create only one route that connects all the points the program is getting. Its incorrect. Help me out pls.